# PHP foreach mysql row update

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
foreach($_POST['categ_name'] as $key => $categ)
{
    $beg = $_POST['beg_count'][$key];
    $del = $_POST['del_count'][$key];
    $ret = $_POST['ret_count'] [$key];
    $exc = $_POST['exc_count'] [$key];
    $pout = $_POST['pout_count'] [$key];
    $sales = $_POST['sales_count'] [$key];
    $end = $_POST['end_count'] [$key];
    $actual = $_POST['actual_count'] [$key];
    $var = $_POST['variance'] [$key];

        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `inventory_report_count` SET `beg` = '$beg' , `del` = '$del' , `ret` = '$ret' , `exc` = '$exc' , `po` = '$pout' ,`sales` = '$sales' ,`end` = '$end' ,`actual_count` = '$actual' ,`variance` = '$var' WHERE `categ_name` = '$categ' ");
        $sql -> execute();
}
```

When i run the code above on localhost, nothing gets updated but when i tried to echo all the variables inside the loop, i got all the correct values. Anyone here who can shed some light?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: fixed it. It seems that the value of $categ includes an extra white space at the end so it doesn't match with the value in the db.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in the correct way instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: can you print `print_r($conn->errorInfo());` after the prepare command?

Comment: Use error handling of the db connection. Output generated SQL and enter it in your mysql client. After all use parameters in your prepared statement and bind them.

Comment: @AgamBanga here's the result of the print_r: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )` It seems that only the last iteration works and gets recorded in the DB, the first two is getting skipped for some unknown reason. I still get the correct values when echoing the variables.

Comment: @tyy007 Also replace this `$sql -> execute();` to `var_dump($sql -> execute());`. Check if in any case it return 0

Comment: @AgamBanga hey i just tried it and it returns 3 bool(true) along with the earlier print_r 0s.

Comment: It means the query is executing successfully. Now we need to check the query itself, Maybe `$categ` is coming incorrectly. Print all the queries.

Comment: @AgamBanga the outputs are: `hp men 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -1 hp women 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1 Total HP 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 -2` wherein hp men, hp women, and Total HP are $categ values and indicates the start of the iteration.

Comment: obvious question, but have you actually got any rows in your table where the categ_name field matches "hp men" or "hp women", or "Total HP"? If these are pre-defined categories I think the database would be better designed using a reference table, and then a foreign key to the inventory report table, so you'd just have the Category ID in there to match on, rather than brittle string matching.

Comment: Have you tried to echo your query, I believe that would not able to parse the variable you are trying to assign as you are using single quotes like '$beg'  can you try it with '"$beg"' and for others too ?